# How to parse twitter using python and based on geolocation?

Tags: geolocation, tweets

I am trying to parse the twitters on specific topic using Python. However, the code runs flawlessly but I need to add the geolocation as one of the core search criteria in parsing. Any suggestion how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more example code?

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could use the [tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/) library. This could also be achieved using Get requests.

I'll provide a Tweepy example:

```
# enter twitter info from [Twitter developers site][2]         
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
ACCESS_KEY = ''
ACCESS_SECRET = ''

# setup authorization
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Location based search can be done using geocode in the `tweepy.search` function:

```
# skeleton query:
geo_based_tweets = api.search(q='some text I want to search on', geocode='long,lat,radius')

# example query about the vikings in Minneapolis:
api.search(q="vikings OR football", geocode='44.9833,-93.2667,10km', count=100)
```

Hope that's helpful!